# Google Calendar API Create/Get Events - ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to access the calendar events of users who ever signs in to my application 
using google oath, also should able to create event from my app. How can I do this using ASP.NET C#?

I could able to access my Calendar events by using client id/secret key that I created during
calendar API project creation process in following url:

https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=calendar&pli=1

Any help or sample code is appreciated.

Here is my code which I used :

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(

    new ClientSecrets
     {
                    ClientId = "Client-Id",
                    ClientSecret = "Client-Secret",
                },
                new[] { CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None).Result;

       

            // Create the service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            CalendarListResource.ListRequest cal = service.CalendarList.List();
            cal.MaxResults = 100;
            
               var calresult = cal.Execute().Items;
            
            
            List<EventDetails> ed = new List<EventDetails>();
  
                foreach (CalendarListEntry entry in calresult)
                {
                   EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List(entry.Id);
                        request.TimeMin = Convert.ToDateTime("03/01/2015");
                        request.ShowDeleted = false;
                        request.SingleEvents = true;
                        request.MaxResults = 200;
                        request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

                        // List events.
                        Events events = request.Execute();
                }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Normally, people post here with a clearly defined problem.  "This is throwing this error", "When I try to X it does Y, I need it to do Z".  It looks like you have written some code, so what's wrong with it?

Comment: This code works for my google account which pulls the events for my calendars, but when I use other email address it gives permission denied error.

Comment: One other issue is I can able to access the calendar events using my account using oauth in my local machine, but when  deploy the same code to server gets this error. "System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. - System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'Google.Apis.Auth' is denied"

Answer (score 1):

**Auth:**

When you run your code the following code will pop up and request the users authenticate your application.

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(

new ClientSecrets
 {
                ClientId = "Client-Id",
                ClientSecret = "Client-Secret",
            },
            new[] { CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

The key here is "user" by default the library stores the credentials in %appdata% directory on your machine.   Each user whos data you wish to access will have to grant you access to their account.

> Error from comment: when I use other email address it gives permission denied error.

I am not sure where you are supplying this other email address but make sure that you have changed the "user" in your code to ensure that you are authenticated with the user whos account you wish to access

> Error from comment Access to the path 'Google.Apis.Auth' is denied"

By default filedatastore stores the credentials in %appData% folder it sounds like your server does not have access to said folder.  I have an article that explains how to change it [FileDatastore demystified](http://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/)

**Scope:**

Scope denotes what type of access you will want CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly is only going to give you read only access to the users account

*Note: I am not sure what you mean by accessing your calendar vs accessing a users calendar.  If you want to give them access to your calendar you should be using a service account.*

Comment: Hi , Can you please help me on this? I posted detail info below. Thanks.

Comment: Used following code, But server is unresponsive.                                                                                                               using (var stream =
            new FileStream(clientSecretsJsonFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user", CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        }

Comment: Tried to add Drive.Api.Auth.Store for Filedatestore, Gives following error "Access to the path 'Drive.Api.Auth.Store' is denied."

Comment: I would assume then that IIS doesn't have access to the path.